# Anyone know how I can add basic web form controls to my Assets library in Fireworks?

Tags: website-design, adobe-fireworks

It has shapes and styles for shapes and things like that, but what I want is to quickly throw some basic form controls like radio buttons, input boxes, list boxes, drop downs, etc. for prototyping and the like, how can I get these into Fireworks? Maybe someone has a .zip file of them somewhere? Or perhaps I'm going to have to draw them manually... hopefully not.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't jumped to the newer versions of FW for wireframing yet, but it looks like it does ship with GUI libraries:

http://www.ixda.org/node/20819

Answer (score 1):

check this link might be it can help you..

http://speckyboy.com/2008/08/28/75-powerful-adobe-fireworks-extensions-it-really-can-be-as-great-as-photoshop/

Answer (score 1):

What version of FW are you using? At least from CS3 if you open up the common library, under the html folder you can get rich symbols with basic html form controls.

more info here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/fireworks/articles/fireworks_web_design_css.html